# Codebehind not detecting display altered in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a tbody inside a table that is displayed/hidden from a javascript call, when a textbox inside the tbody is modified. This tbody is initially set to display = none from its initial markup, but then is shown in the codebehind if it already has contained a value.

Markup:

```
<tbody  class="tbDOIndustryModifierCls" style="width: 100%;display:none;margin:0" id="tbDOIndustryModifierComments" runat="server">
     <td>
         <asp:Label CssClass="raterLabel lblDOIndustryModifierComments" ID="Label11" runat="server">&emsp;&emsp;Comments:
         </asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td colspan="2">
         <asp:textbox Width="100%" ID="txtDOIndustryModifierComments" CssClass="txtDOIndustryModifierComments" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
     </td>
</tbody>
```

Codebehind page load:

```
 If Not IsNothing(comment) Then
      txtDOIndustryModifierComments.Text = comment
      tbDOIndustryModifierComments.Style.Add(DISPLAY, BLOCK)
 End If
```

So the scenario is that the "comment" field has a value, so this `tbody` is set to `display=BLOCK` in the codebehind on page load. Then the user messes with a control and this same `tbody` is set to display=none (via jquery `hide()`).

I also have a "save" button which is handled in my vb.net codebehind.

The issue I'm having is that I can change the tbody's display property to "none" through `javascript` (using `jquery` `hide()`), but when I hit the save button, the codebehind still sees the `tbody` as `display = block`.

codebehind save method (this check is evaluating to false after `javascript` sets `display=none`)

```
 If (tbDOIndustryModifierComments.Style(DISPLAY) = NONE) Then _
 'logic
```

Is there any way to look at whether the `tbody` (or its textbox) is hidden or displayed in the codebehind if the property is modified client-side?

Sorry if my wording is off, let me know anything I can clarify. Thank you for your time.

Comment: use an hiddenfield and read it from request.form

Comment: Thank you, I did consider this but wanted to avoid adding more fields since I will have several of these tbody in the page. But it seems this may be my only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information that is passed back to the server on a post-back are values held in elements like `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `<select>` as well as information stored by ASP.NET in the view state (which itself is stored in `<input type='hidden'>`.  (These are the base HTML elements that are created (rendered) by ASP.NET when your page is displayed.)

What this means is that if you change anything outside of those base elements dynamically on the client-side, they will NOT automatically be sent back to the server.

What I would suggest you do is create a new `<asp:HiddenField>` which will store the state of your table-body.  Then on the post-back you can use the value in that field see whether you need to show/hide your table-body.

(Remember to also set the value in the hidden field on the initial render of the page, so that you get the correct value back even if you don't change anything)

Comment: Thanks, I've already known I could do it this way, but was hoping for another way. The reason is i will have several of these tbody controls and didn't want to have to add more markup, but I guess this is the only way.

Comment: Not a problem - and sorry it's not better news, but that is the way of ASP.NET, you have to live with what's available.  Good luck with your project :-)

Comment: +1 because you explained about viewstate and the fact that many things are not passed back to the server, but you don't *need* to use ASP.Net controls.  You can put an HTML element on an aspx page and reference it in the code behind as `Request["elementID"]`.  I rarely use ASP.Net controls as I find them to be a long-winded pain in the arse!

Comment: Thanks for your vote of confidence @Archer.  In my defence I do say `I would suggest`, but fully agree that you could just use direct HTML

Comment: I didn't mean that as a criticism - sorry if it came across that way.  I just wanted to make the OP aware.  AFAIC, something having 2 different IDs is more than enough to put me off :p